# Citation and reference list isn't working

Tags: biblatex

I have issues with setting up citations in the text itself and creating a reference list. I used jabref to create citations and I saved the bib-data as Literatur.bib in the folder in which I have all other files. Shortended Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
This is supposed to be a quote here \cite{Example2000}.
\newpage
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

In text, the citation appears as Example2000 in bold letterings, not as supposed in (Example, 2000). A reference list is not set up.

Warnings:

> 'babel' option is deprecated, use 'autolang' instead.
>           Citation 'Example2000' on page 4 undefined
>           Empty bibliography
>           There were undefined references.
>           Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) Abschlussbericht(biblatex) and
>           rerun LaTeX afterwards.

In the bib-data, the reference looks like:

```
@Article{Example2000,
  Title                    = {Test},
  Author                   = {Example, V.},
  Journal                  = {Example magazine},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {33-37},
  Volume                   = {8},
}
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Did you run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex?

Comment: Yes, did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). (As per a comment by the user posted as an answer that has been removed since.) The clue is in the error message `Please (re)run Biber on the file ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you define your used languages. Looks like you're using depracted code. You didn't load the `babel`-package for example. Look at your updated MWE. Now it should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}%mod.

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%added
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}%mod.
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}%mod.
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}%include your bib-file for testing purposes
\begin{filecontents}{Literatur.bib}
@Article{Example2000,
  Title                    = {Test},
  Author                   = {Example, V.},
  Journal                  = {Example magazine},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {33-37},
  Volume                   = {8},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
This is supposed to be a quote here \cite{Example2000}.
% \newpage
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my case, I did not inbound biber.exe in TeXStudio. That's why it did not work. To do this: options --> configure TeXStudio --> commands --> link biber.exe in the section "biber"