# Biblatex & Biber still dysfunctional - need some help (is there something wrong in code)?

Tags: biblatex, biber, texstudio

I still have issues with biblatex and biber, citations are not produced properly, a reference list is not set up. I also run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex (F6-F11-F6) in TeXStudios.

I implemented the code suggested here [Citation and reference list isn't working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175628/citation-and-reference-list-isnt-working), but it's still not working.

Could you have a look on my code, maybe you find the problem?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%added
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}%mod.
    \usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}%mod.
    \usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
    \addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Test}
    This is a test \cite{Test2000}. 
    \printbibliography 
    \end{document}
```

In Literatur.bib, I have properly implemented the Test2000 cite:

```
    @Article{Test2000,
      Title                    = {This is a testing title},
      Author                   = {Test, V.},
      Journal                  = {Example magazine},
      Year                     = {2000},
      Pages                    = {33-37},
      Volume                   = {8}
    }
```

Errors:
Zeile 147: Citation 'Test2000' on page 6 undefined Zeile 182: Empty bibliography: There were undefined references. Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) AbschlussberichtX(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards

Comment: Please edit your question to be a "minimal working example" that is, _remove_ all packages unrelated to the problem, while making sure the posted code demonstrates the problem, and say exactly what doesn't work, if you get an error paste the exact error message.

Comment: Ok, i changed it to give others the opportunity to learn from my case. Best wishes.

Comment: simple misconfiguration of the environment

Answer (score 2):

[image: For learning purposes]

Before it was set to biber, my standard bibliography was set for bibtex. After I changed it to biber, it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the \printbibliography at the end

Eg, minus the preamble

```
\begin{document}

\section{Test}
This is a test \cite{Test2000}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, I just forget it to add in my code here,.. added it now - in whole document, it was already included. Still not working.

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe you should post your error log file. See edit above. Just try to compile couple more times.

Comment: Zeile 147: Citation 'Test2000' on page 6 undefined
Zeile 182: Empty bibliography: There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) AbschlussberichtX(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Comment: Make sure you actually run biber and not bibtex

Comment: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1909/wie-verwende-ich-biber-in-meinem-editor?Seite=1#1910

Comment: Ok, this was a useful hint! I defined my biber.exe, but I did not set biber for bibtex. Now it's working! Thx

Comment: Cool. Happy tex'ing. Don't forget to accept the answer so that the question is "solved". Cheers